# Smooth anchor scroll to specific url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have managed to include smooth anchor scroll to my page. However, it crashes with a rootwizard I also have on the page. So here is the question: **How do I add smooth anchor scroll to ONE specific URL?**

**HTML:**

```
<a class="scroll" href="#trinnfortrinn"><div class="kvit handlingsdriver grow">Link
</div></a>
```

**Example of one of the smooth anchor scroll I have tried:**

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I have tried to look it up, both here on Stackoverflow and on Google, but I can't find any answer. Could you please help me out?

**Rootwizard (if needed)**

```
<div class="container rootwizard">
        <div id="rootwizard">
            <div class="navbar">
              <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="bar" class="progress progress-striped active">
                <div class="bar"></div>
                </div>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
                     [...]
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                     [...]
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                     [...]
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
                     [...]
                </div>                   
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's a rootwizard?

Comment: @Sidd It's a Bootstrap plugin which allows to build a wizard functionality using buttons to go through the different wizard steps and using events allows to hook into each step individually. I will try to add the rootwizard in a sec.